# is it possible to avoid nested subscription?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm using angular and `rxJS` I'm pretty new to `rxJS` operators and can't find a way to keep everything inside a stream.

My stream is pretty long so I'll get straigth to the point explaining the problem I'm dealing with

I need to run parralel `Observables` that can be triggered multiple times and process their data in the same manner, but their subscription needs to be in a certain order. for example

```typescript
    firstObservable$.pipe(
      map(() => secondObservable$),//this will only be triggered once
      tap(value => doSomething(value)),//data is processed once following the stream
      mergeMap(() => ThirdObservable$),//this one will be triggered multiple times but is subscribed in a particular order
      tap(value => doAnotherThing(value)),//how can I attach the processing og data to the observable?
      mergeMap(() => FourthObservable$),//this one will be triggered multiple times but is subscribed in a particular order
      tap(value => andAnother(value)),//how can I attach the processing og data to the observable?
      map(() => FifthObservable$),//this will only be triggered once
      tap(value => again(value))//data is processed once following the stream
    ).subscribe()
```

now my problem is that if `ThirdObservable$` is triggered as second time it will continue the rest of the stream and call `FourthObservable$` and `FifthObservable$` I would like the equivalent of

```typescript
    firtsObservable$.subscribe( // triggered Once
      (value) => secondObservable$.subscribe( // triggered Once
        (secondValue) => {
          processSecondValueOnce(secondValue)
          ThirdObservable$.subscribe(thirdValue => process(thirdValue)) // this can be triggered multiple times
          fourthObservable$.subscribe(fourthValue => process(fourthValue)) // this can be triggered multiple times
          fifthObservable$.subscribe( // triggered Once
            (fifthValue) => {
              process(fifthValue)
            }
          )
        }
      )
    )
```

Comment: This sounds tricky to get right. Have you thought about architecting this differently? What other options have you thought about?

Comment: @ShafiqJetha I've thought about making all subscription called once follow one stream operator and for the other ones make them nested

Comment: It looks you're looking for `switchMap` but I probably don't undestand how exactly this all should work

Comment: hello @martin, first thank you for your interest in my problem. Basically I should be calling a ceratin number of observable in a certain order but certain ones should be triggered back independently from the stream in a sense that they shouldn't be triggering the other ones, third shouldn't be triggerring fouth and fifth when triggered again, does that make sense. Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right your question you may want to try something like this

```
firstObservable$.pipe(
  map(() => secondObservable$),
  tap(value_1 => doSomething(value_1)),
  mergeMap(() => {
     // create 3 separate observables, each doing its specific processing
     third = ThirdObservable$.pipe(tap(value => doAnotherThing(value));
     fourth = FourthObservable$.pipe(tap(value => andAnother(value));
     fifth = FifthObservable$).pipe(tap(value => again(value));
     // return the merge of the 3 observables
     return merge(third, fourth, fifth);
  })
).subscribe()
```

I have a point though I do not understand. In the first `map` operator you return an Observable (`secondObservable$`). This means that the variable I called `value_1` will contain an Observable and therefore `doSomething` must be a function which expects an Observable as input. Is this what you really want?

Generally, in situations like this, you want to use "higher-order" operators like `switchMap`, `mergeMap`, `concatMap` or `exaustMap`. These are operators that expect, as input, a function which returns an Observable and "flatten" the return Observable. Maybe this is what you want as well.

Comment: thank you for your answer i'll have adeeper look later, I only hoped there would be a more "unique-stream" solution. Many thanks, btw I upvoted, thanks for your time

Comment: I meant to trigger second observable then retrieve value, but I may be doing it wrong